# Need to have separate notification channels per environment

Tags: terraform

I am trying to write a single `google_monitoring_alert_policy` resource for both prod and dev and I seem to be having an issue with having separate notification channels per environment.

This is what I have now:

```
resource "google_monitoring_notification_channel" "pagerduty" {
  #Only use pagerduty in prod
  count        = "${var.environment == "production" ? 1 : 0}"
  display_name = "Pagerduty Alerting"

  type = "pagerduty"

  labels = {
    service_key = "${var.pagerduty_service_key}"
  }
}
```

```
resource "google_monitoring_alert_policy" "noisy_zk" {
...
  notification_channels = [
    "${split(" ", var.environment == "production" ? "${google_monitoring_notification_channel.pagerduty.name} ${google_monitoring_notification_channel.slack.name}" : "${google_monitoring_notification_channel.slack.name}")}",
  ]
```

Basically what I'm trying to achieve is that I only want to create and use the pagerduty resource in production envs. The error Im getting is this:

```
Error: Error running plan: 1 error occurred:
    * module.stackdriver.google_monitoring_alert_policy.noisy_zk: 1 error occurred:
    * module.stackdriver.google_monitoring_alert_policy.noisy_zk: Resource 'google_monitoring_notification_channel.pagerduty' not found for variable 'google_monitoring_notification_channel.pagerduty.name'
```

Which seems to indicate TF wants to render out all variables even if they're not in use. Any ideas welcome!

Comment: Which version of Terraform are you using? At a glance this should work in 0.12 but needs some ugly hacks to work in 0.11.

Comment: Yeh, we're unfortunately on 0.11, but on the path to 0.12. I've just created the resource and left it disconnected in the channel list. Once we upgrade, I'll just nuke the resource. Thanks for looking for me!

Answer (score 1):

This wasn't exactly solved since this is due to a bug in versions <0.12. So I've just created the resource and will remove it once we upgrade.